# How does the <XsdCodeGenNamespaceMappings> string property work?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am using `<PropertyGroup><XsdCodeGenEnabled>true</XsdCodeGenEnabled></PropertyGroup>` in my .csproj project file to generate C# classes for the XML schema defined in an .xsd file in the project.

I can see that this generates classes in a namespace called ContractTypes by default, and this works because a .targets file in the XsdCodeGen target is setting the value of the XsdCodeGenNamespaceMappings property as `<XsdCodeGenNamespaceMappings>*, ContractTypes</XsdCodeGenNamespaceMappings>` and I can set the property the same way but substitute a namespace I want for 'ContractTypes'

The problem I have is that I want to generate C# types from *multiple* .xsd files in separate namespaces. I am guessing that XsdCodeGenNamespaceMappings is intended to solve this problem, I can see that it is used to build a Dictionary which somehow looks up what output namespace to use. And I don't understand what (in the .xsd file) the input namespace is coming from. ('*' is a magic value.)

How does the XsdTypeImporterTask which does the work actually process the 'NamespaceMappings' parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some diving in the assembly and it looks to me like for *XmlSerializer* mode the only 'input namespace' value supported by XsdBuildTask is `*`. And the only way a namespace mapping dictionary with other values is ever used by the build task is if you're in the *DataContractSerializer* mode. I would be happy to hear I'm wrong however...